# Is there anyway to query components in an Azure Pipeline?

Tags: rest, azure-pipelines

I know one can use REST API to query Pipeline activities but is there anyway to query Pipeline components ( i.e, listing of linked services, sources, sinks, parameters, etc.)

Right now I'm manually recording all the components I see in the pipeline and querying these components would make this listing faster and more accurate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXsUl.png)

Thanks, Jeannie

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to get all the components of a pipeline directly. If the information you want to obtain is defined in the YAML file, you cannot directly obtain it, you may need to parse the YAML file to obtain it.
If the information you want to get is defined on the UI, such as variables, you can get it through the REST API [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). And you can get the resources of the pipeline through [Resources - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/resources/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).